# If $10^{20} +20^{10}$ is divided by 4 then what would be its remainder?

Tags: arithmetic

If $$10^{20} +20^{10}$$ is divided with 4 then what would be its remainder?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila has changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
10^{20}+20^{10} &=&\left( 10^{10}\right) ^{2}+2^{10}10^{10} \\
&=&10^{10}\left( 10^{10}+2^{10}\right)  \\
&=&2^{10}5^{10}\left( 2^{10}5^{10}+2^{10}\right)  \\
&=&2^{10}2^{10}5^{10}\left( 5^{10}+1\right)  \\
&=&4^{10}5^{10}\left( 5^{10}+1\right)  \\
&=&4\left( 4^{9}5^{10}\left( 5^{10}+1\right) \right) ,
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

the remainder <del>would be</del> is $0$, because

$$\frac{10^{20}+20^{10}}{4}=4^{9}5^{10}\left( 5^{10}+1\right).$$

Answer (score 5):

It would be zero.

Namely, $10^{20} = (10^2)^{10}$, and since $4$ divides both $10^2 = 100$ and $20$, it will also divide $100^{10}+20^{10}$.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

As $4$ divides $20 \implies 4$ divides  $20^n$ for any integer $n\ge 1$

As $4$ divides $10^2\implies 4$ will divide $10^m$ for any integer $m\ge2$